# how to change className depending on condition while looping over a list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following piece of code for my component

```
const Booking = (props) => {
    return (
            <li 
                className={props.completed ? 'completed' : 'incomplete'}
                key={props.id}
                id={props.id}
            >
                <h3>{props.date}</h3>
                <h4>{props.time}</h4>
                <h5>{props.name}</h5>
            </li>

    )
}
```

In another component, I am creating multiple of these 'Booking' components, by filling in the details with info that come from a json file

```
const DisplayBookings = () => {

    const display = (day) => allBookings.map(item =>
        item.day === day &&

        <Booking
            className={item.completed}
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            time={item.time}
            name={item.name}
            date={item.date} 
        />
    )
```

I want each  component to have a class corresponding to their 'completed' status. If true, then show 'completed', else show 'incomplete'. These changes in className are for changing the bg-color of the components.

At the moment, every component will stay the same, as I am unable to get each differet value from the json file.

Comment: You just need to pass completed  props to booking. find snippet code below.

`const DisplayBookings = () => {

    const display = (day) => allBookings.map(item =>
        item.day === day &&

        <Booking
            completed ={true}
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            time={item.time}
            name={item.name}
            date={item.date} 
        />
    )`

Comment: If `item.completed` is supposed to fill `props.completed` in your Booking component it should be `<Booking completed={item.completed}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's bug in your code.

```
    const Booking = (props) => {
    return (
            <li 
                className={props.completed ? 'completed' : 'incomplete'}
                key={props.id}
                id={props.id}
            >
                <h3>{props.date}</h3>
                <h4>{props.time}</h4>
                <h5>{props.name}</h5>
            </li>

    )
}

const DisplayBookings = () => {

    const display = (day) => allBookings.map(item =>
        item.day === day &&

        <Booking
            completed={item.completed}
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            time={item.time}
            name={item.name}
            date={item.date} 
        />
    )
```

You are passing in the DisplayBookings Component a prop "className" but it should be "completed".

Not sure if that would fix your problem but that's something that is not working as expected.